# syslog: Failed start mount ZFS filesystems

Tags: 20.04, zfs

I'm getting this error since trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 20. For the reference, I never wanted to install ZFS on this computer, never did anything to that effect, and, subsequently, there are no ZFS volumes / pools or anything like that on this computer.

Why is this happening / how can I disable this behavior? I don't have a kernel module for ZFS, so there's nothing to blacklist.

I figured that the effects of whatever kernel is doing there might be benign, I still don't want it to spew suspicious errors.

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  You mention both Ubuntu 20 (*snap* based release likely Ubuntu Core 20) but have tagged Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a kernel message, that is a message from a systemd service that mounts ZFS file systems. Something like the following should stop it trying to do that:

```
systemctl disable zfs-mount
systemctl disable zfs-import-cache
```

Or you could just leave it as is, the message doesn't indicate an actual problem.